# Apache crashes after installing mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

System: Apache 2.2 running on Windows 2008 Server with PHP 5.2.17 VC6 Thread-Safe as a Module and MySQL 5.5.17 - all working fine.

After installing mysqli using the php package, Apache won't start anymore. There is no error message in the log.

What I have tried:

- Make sure Windows PATH points to libmysql.dll: Yes, done.
- Make sure extension_dir points to the right point: Yes. Other extensions load fine.
- Try without mysqli: Yes, Apache loads fine then.
- Try without mysql: Yes, does not help.
- Test mysql itself: Restarts server!
- Overwrite libmysql: Yes, does not help.

It seems to me that there is some general problem with MySql, but the DB server seems to be running fine.
I'm really out of ideas of things I could try, so I'm desperate for any hints or tricks.

Comment: is there no command line output with you try to start it?

Comment: no, absolutely none. it returns to the prompt almost immediately. the error log file then claims that "Apache2.2 service is running", but when I try to stop it from the command line it says that "Apache2.2 service is running"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a hidden second mysql installation. Boy, did that take time to figure..

Comment: And I thought your problem was that you were using windows ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting out the php module from httpd.conf?

If that works, try un-commenting the mysql modules from the php.ini file.

Comment: Commenting out php from http.conf will load the server normally. Commenting out mysql from php.ini will still crash.
Commenting out mylsqi from php.ini will load the server normally.

Comment: Should be the mysqli dll. Can you download the latest mysqli.dll and try it. Take a look at the following link which seems to suggest the same  

http://www.rdlt.com/xampp-mysqli-crashes-apache.html